# Получение значения Dictionary<> по индексу

Tags: c#

Как получить значение Dictionary<> по индексу.

Например, у меня есть коллекция:

```
Dictionary<string,string> weather
```

Её я заполняю таким образом:

```
weather.Add("Москва","+3);
weather.Add("Омск","+5");
weather.Add("Челябинск","-100");
```

Все заполняется, в отладчике я вижу, что коллекция weather имеет 3 индекса,
точней три пары значений.

Как я могу обратиться к любому из них? Например, коллекция имеет 10 пар значений и мне нужна 5-я. Могу ли я как-то получить значение напрямую? Например:

```
weather[4].Values
```

Comment: Для получения знаний по индексу используйте массив или список

Comment: Или OrderedDictionary

Comment: В словаре, настоящими индексами являются ваши ключи, доступ по номеру обычно лишён смысла, т. к. порядок элементов не определён. Если вы очень хотите доступ по числовому индексу, используйте тот факт, что `Dictionary<K, V>` реализует `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K, V>>`, и применяйте `.ToList()` или пару `Skip()/First()`.

Comment: @VladD, или просто `.ElementAt()`)

Comment: Если автор прямо в приведенном примере кода напишет `weather.ElementAt(0).Key`, то не факт что он получит результат `Москва`, так же не факт, что этот же результат сохранится после добавления в словарь или удаления из него элементов. @icedev, почему бы вам просто не завести класс со свойствами `Город` и `Температура` и просто хранить коллекцию (`List`) экземпляров этого класса?

Comment: Я люблю давать такие советы, поэтому для всех начинающих прогеров, которые читают комменты и интересуются, почему тут все настырно предлагают другие коллекции вместо словаря: Dictionary - это hash table _внутри_. Поэтому ознакомьтесь с его внутренним устройством: [Хеш-таблица](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Хеш-таблица) - сразу станет понятно, почему порядок не гарантирован и может измениться при добавлении новых элементов.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov: Точно! Забыл про него

Comment: @АндрейNOP так и сделал. Просто изначально хотелось сделать проще , Просто вернуть из функции Dictionary а не писать класс и заворачивать его в List.Оказалось нельзя.Так же наверно...можно было сделать Двумерный List[][]  и в цикле его заполнить. Но с классом все эстетичней выглядит)

Comment: Ну... В нашем деле лучше не лениться, хотя стандартная библиотека всячески этому потворствует (богатый выбор стандартных коллекций, упрощённый синтаксис для кортежей и т.д.). Ждём когда появится упрощённый синтаксис для POCO-классов, а пока пишем по старинке. А вы напишите ответ, чтобы топик не висел открытым.

Answer (score 2):

В словаре, настоящими индексами являются ваши ключи, доступ по номеру обычно лишён смысла, т. к. порядок элементов не определён.